# windows.location.href throws error on IE10 using vbscript

Tags: windows-7, vbscript, internet-explorer-10, window.location

I'm trying to use `Window.Location.Href` in my VBScript code,
this throws me an error on Windows 7, IE 10:

> Object doesn't support this property or method

It's working on XP and it's even working on Win7 if I'm using javascript.

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to `window.location.href` (javascript sintax, no uppercase) and it will work.

Comment: Is this mean I'm using js inside my vbscript?

Comment: No, it means that for some obscure reason the references to objects in IE must follow (not always) the javascript camel case naming. No need to use javascript, only the name of objects/properties/methods exposed by the browser.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Windows 7 IE 10 has some problems with VBScript.  Can you try running your page in IE9 compatibility mode?  If not then try to determine which object/property combination is giving you the problem.  If `Window.Location` is the problem then try just using `Location`.  However, if `Location.Href` is the problem then there may be a security issue going on.

More information on setting compatibility mode at [vbscript is not working on IE10 browser mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14265443/vbscript-is-not-working-on-ie10-browser-mode)

Comment: Yes it is working on compatibility mode, do you know about an official link of MS which state that VBS problems on IE10?

Comment: I don't know of any official document, just the mumblings of the internet in general.